# How can I implement HTML inline styling using variables in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am using VBA to generate a new Outlook Email. My code works as expected when assigning a hard coded table width, however I would like to assign `width: 500px;` to a variable and use the variable throughout the body of my email.

How can I achieve this? I know we cannot use CSS with VBA as we're limited to a bare bones version of HTML via VBA / Outlook

CODE

```
Sub SendEmail
'shortened code
Dim tblWidth as double
tblWidth = 500

'i would like <td style = 'width:tblWidth px;...

With EmailMessage
    .To = "john.smith@yahoo.com"
    '...other email properties listed here
    .HTMLBody = "<table><td style='width:500px; color:#4d4d4d; height=2px;'></td></table>"

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Personally, I prefer using a stylesheet instead of using inline styles. It makes things a lot easier.

Comment: @braX maaan believe me I wish I knew how to incorporate, do you have any good link recommendations?

Comment: i gave you another answer, but I know you already picked the best one per your question using inline styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this simply

```
.HTMLBody = "<table><td style='width:" & tblWidth & "px; color:#4d4d4d; height=2px;'></td></table>"
```

Comment: Thank you! I see now that the quotes go inside

Comment: Yes. To put a variable, surround it with double quotes and use the ampersand `" & tblWidth & "`

Comment: Technically, you are surrounding the literal parts of the string in quotes, and closing them to include a variable. But you can think of it the other way around if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

To use a stylesheet instead:

Just create one using a string and include it in your `HTMLBody`

```
Dim sStyleSheet as String
sStyleSheet = "<style> td {width:500px;} </style>"
```

or to include your variable

```
sStyleSheet = "<style> td {width:" & tblWidth & "px;} </style>"
```

See how you are just building a string?

Then include it in the HTML:

```
sHTML = "<table><tr><td> Hello World </td></tr></table>"
sStyleSheet = "<style> td {width:" & tblWidth & "px;} </style>" 
.HTMLBody = sStyleSheet & sHTML
```

Make sense?

Comment: Nice! Thanks for this!

Comment: I forgot to ask, will this work with ID tags like `#customHeader` to then be used later in my HTML code like so: `<td id='customHeader'>`

Comment: yeah i don't see why not... `td#customHeader {width:500px;}`

Comment: Great, just tried it and so far it is working. Ill write some code up and post it on Code Review, would you mind reviewing?

Comment: i never go to code review, but glad to hear you have it working. with css there typically isnt too much to optimize (for speed) since it's not exactly a compiled language, but you may be able to use fewer lines in the end...

Comment: Just keep in mind that no matter how much CSS you are using, you need only one set of style tags in the string you are building... I'm assuming you will know what that means.

Comment: Yeah, CSS is going to be pretty lengthy as I am generating an email. So only one set of these, '<style>'  '</style>' is what you're referring to right?

Comment: yeah... just one at the start, and the other at the end.